# How to change the TextJoin range in google sheet dynamically based on empty cell

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, concatenation, textjoin

I want to join the text but the number of rows differ for each record. If I use the static range data is missing for few records, in below example 22Inch is missing,

[image]

Used the below formula. How to dynamically change the range.

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A3:A8,"")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, A3:INDEX(A:A, MIN(IFERROR(1/(1/(ROW(A3:A)*(A3:A="")))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this one out:

```
=LAMBDA(z,BYROW(z,LAMBDA(a,REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IFNA(FILTER(A2:A,XLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B),z,z,,-1)=a))),"^(.*?)\,",""))))({ROW();BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(z,IF((z<>"")*(OFFSET(z,-1,0)=""),ROW(z),)))})
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another formula you can try:

`=QUERY(INDEX(LAMBDA(ζ,SORT(REGEXREPLACE(ζ,"^,",),COUNTIFS(A1:A,"",ROW(A1:A),"<="&ROW(A1:A)),1,LEN(ζ),))({"";IF({A3:A;""}<>"",,SCAN(,A2:A,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",,a&","&c))))})),"limit "&ROWS(A2:A))`

[image]